# Can't Click an Element in Python Selenium After Successfully Finding It

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using the following script to find elements called 'service_notes' and click the first of them:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import os


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe')

driver.get("https://.../sites/frontiersupport/servicenotes/Pages/default.aspx")
os.system("java -jar sikulix.jar -r login.sikuli")
driver.implicitly_wait(5) #
service_notes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*/a[starts-with(@href, "/sites/frontiersupport/servicenotes/Lists/SNotes/DispForm.aspx")]')
print(str(service_notes[0]) + ' is the first service note')
print(len(service_notes))
service_notes[0].click()
```

According to the log, the element is found, but for some reason I can't click it:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7505cfd0-5f41-4a8c-af28-bca639e13332", element="c81518a8-5f6c-42fa-8089-5f9469423d7c")> is the first service note
10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 19, in <module>
    service_notes[0].click()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: No modal dialog is currently open
```

The browser is defniitely open, and I'm not sure why the driver is looking for an open 'modal dialog'.  This should simply be clicking a link.   Any ideas?

Here's the HTML of the link I want to click:

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/sites/frontiersupport/servicenotes/Lists/SNotes/DispForm.aspx?ID=14686" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">Firmware 3.04 released for the 850-DS <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." width="1" height="1" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: please post relevant html as well

Comment: @Sighil   I posted the HTML below the question

Comment: what version are you using selenium ?

Comment: @Sighil  I'm using 3.11.0

Comment: @Sighil  And Firefox 52.7.2 (32-Bit)  (newer Firefoxes don't work)

Comment: I am seeing Selenium 3.8.1 as the latest release for selenium python. 3.11.0 might have issues. Could you try 3.81?  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases

Comment: @Sighil  I downgraded to 3.8.1 and I'm getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167269/discussion-between-sighil-and-david-j).

Comment: hey @DavidJ. so if the page is write in angular JS or similar is possible that there are multiple object on the same page, but they are overlap for keep visible just the needed one, so can be that your object is there and selenium find it but, at the same time, selenium is not able to click on it because it has another object in front

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem of not being able to click on elements too. One way I found to go around it was to use [execute_script](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method. In your case -

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", service_notes[0])
```